# Fetching last modifed date for every folder within a sub-directory in AWS S3 using Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to find the last modified date for all folder within S3. Given below is what I have come up this far that lists down all sub-folders within a path. This just displays all the sub-folder names but I am trying to also get the last modified date for each of these folders.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
import pandas as pd


# Create connection
conn = S3Connection(key_id, secret_key)


# Connet to a specific bucket
bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket-name')


# Get subdirectory info
for key in bucket.list(prefix='folder/', delimiter='/',):
    print(key.name)
```

**Update**

View of how the data resides in S3

```
bucket-name
    folder
        sub-folder
            date
                file1.csv
                file2.csv
                file3.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is tagged `boto3`, so I will provide an answer in `boto3`, not `boto`.

```
import boto3

# Create connection
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxx', 
    aws_secret_access_key='yyyyyyyyyyyyyy')

s3r = session.resource('s3')

# Connect to a specific bucket
bucket = s3r.Bucket('bucket-name')

# Get subdirectory info
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='folder/', Delimiter='/'):
    print(obj.key, obj.last_modified)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. However this does not print out the last line when I try to execute and does not throw an error.. Only change I made was set `Prefix='folder/sub-folder/'`

Comment: @KevinNash Not sure what do you mean. It works perfectly. Maybe you could update your question with exactly the folder structure you have and the new version of your code.

Comment: I have edited my initial post with the structure in which the data resides. I am trying to check when was the `date` last modified. Hope this provides some clarity around what I am trying to get. Thanks

Comment: @KevinNash Try without `Delimiter='/'`.

Comment: I did try that and it returns all the files in the sub-folders

Comment: sorry if I did not clearly explain my requirement. I am only trying to get the latest modified date for each `sub-folder`

Comment: I don't think you can get modification times for folders, just files. if you can be certain that a _SUCCESS file will be written in every folder, then you can use the timestamp of that. but otherwise, you'll have to use, as a proxy, the latest modified time of the files in the folder.